# ajax short html function syntax error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

This is my first time to paint a client web page from inside a webmethod function.
Please help and tell me why this syntax is wrong?

This is the all function - that works fine:

```
[WebMethod]
public IList<OrderViewDTO> GetTaskProgress(DateTime xDATEx)
{
    try
    {
        var xDate2 = xDATEx.AddDays(1);
        new OrderDataRepository()
            .GetAllOrderData()
            .Where(x=>x.POD_DATE>=xDATEx && x.POD_DATE < xDate2)
            .GroupBy(o => o.User)
            .Select(g => new OrderViewDTO
            {
                DriverId = g.Key.Id,
                PdriverName = g.Key.Name,
                OrderCount = g.Count(),
                OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull = g.Count(o => o.RECEIVE_NAME != null)
            })
            .ToList();
```

can you please show me how to print a div and a values like  <%# Eval("DriverName") %> inside the div inside the above function
instead of my original code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="DataViewer" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style='border: 1px; width: 600px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;'>
                    <div style='float: left;'>
                        <%# Eval("DriverName") %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div style='border: 3px solid black; float: left; width: <%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("OrderCount")) * 50 %>px'>
                        <div style='border: 0px; float: left; width: <%# ((Convert.ToDouble(Eval("OrderCount")) - Convert.ToDouble(Eval("OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull"))) / Convert.ToDouble(Eval("OrderCount"))) * 100 %>%;'>
                            <%# Eval("OrderCount") %></div>
                        <div style='border: 0px; float: right; width: <%# (Convert.ToDouble(Eval("OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull")) / Convert.ToDouble(Eval("OrderCount"))) * 100 %>%;
                            background-color: red;'>
                            <%# Eval("OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull") %></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Please give full details of why this is not working for you, and what errors you are getting.

Comment: What is `ordersPage.Items`? Doesn't look like something you can iterate over in jQuery...

Comment: i think orderspage.items is json string.

Comment: i've updated the question please see my problem again,10q:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stab in the dark, it looks like you are appending the table rows for the ordersPage.Items to HTML in structure which **alredy has closed its table tag**.

Take the closing table tag out of structure where you are initializing it, and instead append it to structure AFTER the $.each on ordersPage.Items.